# How to upload a video through PHP, and transcode it via FFmpeg

Tags: php, nginx, video, ffmpeg, wowza

Currently I am building a video streaming platform and I need a way to upload my videos, through multiple resolutions to my Wowza server. I am currently running Ubuntu with Nginx, PHP and Wowza so I want to be able to, when the user uploads the video, encode it to 1080p, 720p, 480p, and 360p. How would I do this?

Comment: There's totally a better way to do that. You'd upload the file with a file-upload and then use php to run ffmpeg on the files (concatenate them, compress, etc) then post the files to another server. I've actually done this same thing with Angular, Laravel & Amazon hosting. When FFMPEG is done with the file you'd use curl to send to the remote or maybe ping the remote server to retrieve the file instead?

Comment: @admcfadn | Okay, I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: np, good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the free, open source [Video Share VOD](http://videosharevod.com/) solution that can manage video uploads, conversions to multiple formats. 
You could customise that to add more formats as necessary.
It installs easily with WP framework, requires PHP and FFMPEG on server.

Comment: Yes, however I am not using WordPress (as it limits what I want to do) and I already have Wowza to stream videos.